# Where are files stored in docker daemon?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I tried to add a file via `ADD` command and then deleted it. But the size of docker images also shows that it includes that files! If I put `*` in `.dockerignore`, it will not work with `ADD`.

Dockerfile:

```
from ubuntu:20.04

ADD myfile /tmp

RUN rm /tmp/*
```

Then I built it by
`$ docker build -t testwf .`

At the first stage it shows the below:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  34.21MB
```

The size of `myfile` file is around `33MB`

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                       TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
testwf                           latest    96543168ab34   16 minutes ago   107MB
ubuntu                           20.04     ba6acccedd29   5 weeks ago      72.8MB
```

Actually, I was supposed to get an image with `72.8MB` the same size with `ubuntu` not `107MB` which is roughly equal to `72.8MB` plus `33MB`! In other words, If I didn't have that file with `ADD` command, was there any way to access the file in the container as it was copied to `Docker daemon`?

## update

As [HansKilian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3924803/hans-kilian) mentioned in the comments that file went in one of the layers where the final image is constructed on top of that. Is there any way to get rid of that layer in order to decrease the size of the final image?

```
$ docker history testwf:latest                                                                  
IMAGE          CREATED         CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
2af2733972ab   4 seconds ago   /bin/sh -c rm /tmp/*                            0B
40d13da4e0cc   4 seconds ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:0ddf694d27b108b4a…   34.2MB
ba6acccedd29   5 weeks ago     /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago     /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:5d68d27cc15a80653…   72.8MB
```

Comment: It's because Docker doesn't just store the final image. It stores all the steps needed to get to the final image. It stores each step in it's own 'layer'. In your case, you add two new layers to the ubuntu image: one where the file is included and one where it is removed.

Comment: Actually, when I download that file from the web and then delete it the size of docker image remains fixed! Is there any way to get rid of that file, because it makes the size of docker image unbelievably large?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to "merge" intermediate layers in Docker:

- Multi-stage build as mentioned in Romain Prévost's answer
- `--squash` command options in `docker build` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/
- export a container running the final image with `docker export` and then re-import it by `docker import`.

  - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/
  - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/

More details:

In principle, each command in Dockerfile add a new "layer" containing the file system after command execution in the final image, what Docker helps here is that you may save each layer by only its diff from the **previous layer**, so we don't waste disk space for the same files.
For example, if we execute an `add` then an `remove` commands on top of some layer 0, the `add` command create layer 1 including only the added file. The `remove` commands create layer 2 marking the file as removed. Since each layer only compares its diff with the previous layer, Docker don't know that layer 2 is identical to layer 0 during build. If we repeat the add/delete commands, every time we add, we create an extra layer with size equal to the file. As a result, we may build mulitple images with identical (final) content but varied size. For example, we may create a 32MB file and add/delete it twice to the same image like:

```
from ubuntu:latest

ADD big_file .
RUN rm big_file
ADD big_file .
RUN rm big_file
```

Building it with `docker build . -t big_file:latest` gives a image with size equal to <BASE_SIZE> + 32 MB * 2:

```
REPOSITORY                          TAG        IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
big_file                            latest     ddd32b7a8519   2 minutes ago   140MB
ubuntu                              latest     ba6acccedd29   5 weeks ago     72.8MB
```

We can check layers within `big_file` by `docker history <IMAGE>` and get

```
IMAGE          CREATED         CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
ddd32b7a8519   4 minutes ago   /bin/sh -c rm big_file                          0B        
c20573523c30   4 minutes ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:937071a2cba4a5d8b…   33.6MB    
80ae0642e3ad   4 minutes ago   /bin/sh -c rm big_file                          0B        
0538ebbf489c   4 minutes ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:937071a2cba4a5d8b…   33.6MB    
ba6acccedd29   5 weeks ago     /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B        
<missing>      5 weeks ago     /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:5d68d27cc15a80653…   72.8MB
```

So what do above three methods do?

- multi-stage build

It throw away **all** layers in the previous stage and copy only specified files to the next stage. For example

```
from ubuntu:latest

ADD big_file .
RUN rm big_file
ADD big_file .
RUN rm big_file
ADD big_file .

from ubuntu:latest
COPY --from=0 big_file .
```

Building it gives two image, one for stage-0, another for stage-1.

```
REPOSITORY                          TAG        IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
<none>                              <none>     6d844f18d92e   5 seconds ago    173MB
big_file                            latest     4b1025db1335   33 seconds ago   106MB
ubuntu                              latest     ba6acccedd29   5 weeks ago      72.8MB
```

Check the stage-1 image, it's clear that layers in stage-0 image is not copied. It contains only one extra layer created by `COPY --from=0 big_file .` command.

```
IMAGE          CREATED          CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
4b1025db1335   47 seconds ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:937071a2cba4a5d8…   33.6MB    
ba6acccedd29   5 weeks ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B        
<missing>      5 weeks ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:5d68d27cc15a80653…   72.8MB
```

It suits in situation you are clear what you need from the stage-0 image. A good example is you may compile in stage-0 and copy only the binary to stage-1. One common mistake, however, is that one may forget to copy dynamic libraries required by the binary which are missing in the stage-1 image as these two images are two different images with respective base image and layers.

- `--squash`

It's similar as `squash` in git. It loads and applies diff in each layer to create a new layer and use only the new layer in the built image.

Building using `docker build . -t big_file:latest --squash` gives three image s

```
REPOSITORY                          TAG        IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
big_file                            latest     6903fba8cef3   2 seconds ago   72.8MB
<none>                              <none>     28ed65140111   3 seconds ago   140MB
ubuntu                              latest     ba6acccedd29   5 weeks ago     72.8MB
```

`28ed65140111` is the image before squash, check layers in `big_file`

```
IMAGE          CREATED          CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
6903fba8cef3   10 seconds ago                                                   0B        merge sha256:28ed65140111012d7604df5123b9be16ab4bfc62dd799259001b5d609ceb8e18 to sha256:ba6acccedd2923aee4c2acc6a23780b14ed4b8a5fa4e14e252a23b846df9b6c1
<missing>      11 seconds ago   /bin/sh -c rm big_file                          0B        
<missing>      12 seconds ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:937071a2cba4a5d8b…   0B        
<missing>      13 seconds ago   /bin/sh -c rm big_file                          0B        
<missing>      14 seconds ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:937071a2cba4a5d8b…   0B        
<missing>      5 weeks ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B        
<missing>      5 weeks ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:5d68d27cc15a80653…   72.8MB
```

After load all diffs, there is nothing different from the base image, so the merge layer `6903fba8cef3` is empty. But `squash` build is currently an experimental feature.

- export/import

Notice that export works for a **container** rather than a **image**, it only dumps the current state of the container's file system, and ignores layer informations in the **image**. If we dump one container running our `big_file` image and then re-import it using `docker export <CONTAINER_ID> > big_file.tar && docker import - big_file:load < big_file.tar`, we get an "empty" image looks like:

```
IMAGE          CREATED          CREATED BY   SIZE      COMMENT
06f4d01022e7   13 seconds ago                72.8MB    Imported from -
```

Now we can't know how the image is built since layers are not dumped.

Which one is better really depends..., but the concept of layer in Docker is very important. Docker never forgets anything unless you drop or merge the layer somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately, the multistage build does not help me in this case as the size is still `107MB` even if I set the last command `RUN rm /tmp/*`. The `--squash` is only supported on a Docker daemon with experimental features enabled!. The export/import makes a concise image but I want to do it in the Dockerfile.

Comment: The multistage doesn't help here because the big_file is still copied to Stage-1 image by `COPY --from=0 /tmp/myfile ./` in Maroun's example. The copy create a layer 0, then `rm /tmp/*` create another layer 1, so `big_file` still exists in layer 0. Multistage may help only when you don't copy big file to the stage-1 image. You can finish all steps depending on the file in stage-0 image, and copy nenessary file s excluding the big file to stage-1 image.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a Docker multistage build, where you first use an image for your build, with all your dependencies, and then build a new image with only the relevant artifacts. That way you don't have to delete the files you don't need, so much as simply not include them.

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Answer (score 1):

You can have a [multistage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) build:

```
FROM alpine:latest  
ADD myfile /tmp

from ubuntu:20.04
COPY --from=0 /tmp/myfile ./
RUN rm /tmp/*
```

Comment: Does not work for me! It is still 107MB!

Comment: Actually, with/without the last line--`RUN rm /tmp/*`--, the image size is `107MB`!